IntelliJ reporting "cannot resolve symbol" for a javadoc @link to a symbol in a different module not imported
IntelliJ is showing an @link in red and reporting "Cannot resolve symbol" - the link reference is valid: the fully qualified package.class#method(args) exists - but it is in a module not imported into the current module.
Sure enough, the Javadoc tool will also fail to resolve this symbol.
Is there a way to make it work without importing the other module?
For system architecture purposes the other module is not to be imported to the module in question.  But does that mean I can't even properly link to a valid symbol over there?  There may be good reasons why I want to link to it - it might have an illuminating Javadoc comment itself - even though I'm not allowed to reference the symbol in code.
[IntelliJ IDEA 2024.3 Ultimate, Java 21 making full use of modules]
